# Group by historical date for each date in the provided range

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Am stuck with this for days. wanna group a sql result set by historical dates. so want a result to be grouped by date from each date in the date specified range all the way back in time. Here is my sql so far, but it groups the result by date instead of historical date.

Please help!

```
SELECT ledger.transdate,
sum(case when transcodes.dtcr = 'C' then ledger.amount else 0 end) Credit,
sum(case when transcodes.dtcr = 'D' then ledger.amount else 0 end) Debit,
sum(case when transcodes.dtcr = 'C' then ledger.amount else 0 end) -
sum(case when transcodes.dtcr = 'D' then ledger.amount else 0 end) Balance
FROM
  LEDGER
  INNER JOIN TRANSCODES ON (LEDGER.TRANSCODE = TRANSCODES.TRANSCODE)
 where ledger.transdate >= '2013-02-28' and ledger.transdate <= '2013-03-01'
 group by ledger.transdate
```

Comment: Please can you clarify what you mean by historical date vs date

Comment: What do you mean by "historical date"?

Comment: group by sum of the records from 2013-02-28 all the way back, some records from 2013-02-29 all the way back, some records from 2013-03-01 all the way back, etc

Comment: And your transdate field also contains time?

Comment: transdate does not contain time.

Comment: If you can show us what query result you get now, and what you want to get, would be easier.

Comment: It looks like each date group should contain the sum of all previous records so as to show the acccount balance at each date. A running total: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_total

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider this example...

```
SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+

 SELECT x.i, SUM(y.i) running FROM ints x JOIN ints y ON y.i <= x.i GROUP BY i;
+---+---------+
| i | running |
+---+---------+
| 0 |       0 |
| 1 |       1 |
| 2 |       3 |
| 3 |       6 |
| 4 |      10 |
| 5 |      15 |
| 6 |      21 |
| 7 |      28 |
| 8 |      36 |
| 9 |      45 |
+---+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, and you want to group by date-only part of transdate field, you can use Date() function, i.e. ... group by Date(transdate)

Answer (score 0):

Your answer can be found here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/300785/Calculating-simple-running-totals-in-SQL-Server